# Windows Forms ComboBox problem

Tags: winforms

I have a combobox that goes out to the database to load it's content on clicking the dropdown arrow. if after the dropdown box is shown with data and I don't select anything, than the current value of the combobox is blown away. Inside my routine to load data, I tried saving the current value and restoring it back after the loading is done. doesn't work.

[Edit] Added the code from the comment here for legibility

```
MyUltraCombo myultracombo = new MyUltraCombo(); 
//MyUltraCombo inherits from UltraCombo inside MyUltraCombo, I keep the table name to load from 
MyUltraCombo.BeforeDropDown += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(cb_BeforeDropDown); 
//inside the eventhandler 
myultracombo.Load(); 
//inside the Load method 
datatable = DataUtility.GetAllRecords(tablename); 
combobox.datasource = datatable;
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: MyUltraCombo myultracombo = new MyUltraCombo();

MyUltraCombo inherits from UltraCombo
inside MyUltraCombo, I keep the table name to load from

MyUltraCombo.BeforeDropDown += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(cb_BeforeDropDown);

inside the eventhandler
myultracombo.Load();
inside the Load method
datatable = DataUtility.GetAllRecords(tablename);
combobox.datasource = datatable

Answer (score 1):

If you store "the current value" as just the `SelectedItem` property, then it will probably not be an object that is present in the new list, since it will consist of completely new objects. What you will have to do is store an ID of the current value (if you're lucky to have a unique id) and then search the newly created list for an object with the same id (or whatever you use to uniquely identify an item, maybe just `ToString()`...).